# Etiquette of uploading original work

Tags: work

I do not know if this is the right platform to ask this or not.

When we upload our original work on a platform like Behance or Dribble should we use a watermark on those works?

In past, I have been a victim of being robbed, my original ideas and works were snatched by Ethicless humans :@, So I need to know this.

I spend days, and sleepless nights brainstorming and when that happens that's unacceptable.

if this question is against the site rules I will remove it.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Thank you Billy Kerr.

Comment: Some people have no etiquette.